# Python - For Loop ( two parallel iterations)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, for-loop

I am working on the estimation module of a prototype. The purpose is to send proper seasonality variation parameters to the forecaster module.

Initially, in the booking curve estimation, we were using a formula for day of year seaonality - trigonometric function with 5 orders (fixed). It goes like this:

```
doy_seasonality = np.exp(z[0]*np.sin(2*np.pi*doy/365.)+z[1]*np.cos(2*np.pi*doy/365.)
                       +z[2]*np.sin(4*np.pi*doy/365.)+ z[3]*np.cos(4*np.pi*doy/365.)
                       +z[4]*np.sin(6*np.pi*doy/365.)+ z[5]*np.cos(6*np.pi*doy/365.)
                       +z[6]*np.sin(8*np.pi*doy/365.)+ z[7]*np.cos(8*np.pi*doy/365.)
                       + z[8]*np.sin(10*np.*pi*doy/365.)+ z[9]*np.cos(10*np.pi*doy/365.))
```

i.e. we had 5 fixed orders `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`

Now, we have found a better way to get the orders through Fast Fourier Transform. Depending on the estimation key we use as input in the simulation, the order array could have different number of values.

For instance, let's say the order array is as follows

```
orders = [2, 6, 10, 24]
```

Corresponding to every order value, there would be two values of z (it's a trigonometric parameter - one value for SIN part and one value for COS part). For example, it could look like this

```
z = [0.08 0.11 0.25 0.01 0.66 0.19 0.45 0.07]
```

To achieve this, I would need to define a for-loop with two parallel iterations:

```
z[0] to z[2*length(orders)-1]      i.e. `z[0] to z[7]`
```

and `orders[0] to orders[length(orders)-1]     i.e. orders[0] to orders[3]`

ultimately, the formula should compute this:

```
doy_seasonality = np.exp(z[0]*np.sin(orders[0]*np.pi*doy/365.)+z[1]*np.cos(orders[0]*np.pi*doy/365.)
                       +z[2]*np.sin(orders[1]*np.pi*doy/365.)+ z[3]*np.cos(orders[1]*np.pi*doy/365.)
                       +z[4]*np.sin(orders[2]*np.pi*doy/365.)+ z[5]*np.cos(orders[2]*np.pi*doy/365.)
                       +z[6]*np.sin(orders[3]*np.pi*doy/365.)+ z[7]*np.cos(orders[3]*np.pi*doy/365.))
```

I am not able to design the appropriate syntax for this.

doy (day of year) is a vector taking equally spaced values : 1, 2, 3... 364, 365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
orders = np.array([2, 6, 10, 24])
z = np.array([0.08, 0.11, 0.25, 0.01, 0.66, 0.19, 0.45, 0.07])
doy = np.arange(365) + 1

s = 0
for k in range(len(orders)):
    s += z[2 * k    ] * np.sin(orders[k] * np.pi * doy / 365.)
    s += z[2 * k + 1] * np.cos(orders[k] * np.pi * doy / 365.) 
s = np.exp(s)
```